# Express: composing middleware

Tags: node.js, express

I want to move a series of `app.use()` calls into its own module. The easiest way to encapsulate this is to expose a `function(app)` in the exports, but I feel that handing over the `app` object is too much of an opaque interface.

I would like to expose a middleware to be `app.use()`'d from outside the module. I need to chain/compose the middlewares used internally.

Is there a stylish way of doing this, or an alternative? What's the easiest way of going about it? Anything I should avoid?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This answer is a little late, but here it goes anyway...

```
// composedMiddleware.js
const express = require('express')
const ware1 = (req, res, next)=>{...}
const ware2 = (req, res, next)=>{...}
const router = express.Router()
router.use(ware1)
router.use(ware2)
export default router

// app.js
const composedMiddleWare = require('./composedMiddleware.js')
app.get('/something', (req, res, next)=>{...})
app.get('/something', composedMiddleWare)
```

If the code isn't self-explanatory, then just note that routers are also middleware. Or, to put it more precisely, "a router behaves *like* middleware itself, so you can use it as an argument to app.use()" [ref](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router).

Comment: Yup. A one-liner: `const combinedMw = Router().use([mw1, mw2, mw3])`.
And then you can use it: `combinedMw(req, res, next)` or pass it where you need to.

Answer (score 2):

Glancing through the code for Express (and Connect, on which it is based), it appears that calling `use` on a piece of middleware does not notify anything in any way, so there's really no way to compose things ahead of time without passing in `app`.

You could, however, do the composition at run time, e.g. the first time your middleware is called, compose some functions together and cache/call them.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my take:

```
// app.js
...
app.use(require('./middleware')());
...

// middleware.js
var express    = require('express');    
module.exports = function() {
  var middleware = [
    // list of middleware that you want to have performed:
    function mymiddleware(req, res, next) {
      console.log('hello world');
      next();
    },
    express.logger('dev'),
    express.cookieParser(),
    express.static(__dirname)
  ];
  return function(req, res, next) {
    (function iter(i, max) {
      if (i === max) {
        return next();
      }
      middleware[i](req, res, iter.bind(this, i + 1, max));
    })(0, middleware.length);
  };
};
```

If you need access to the app in your custom middleware, you can access it through `req.app` or `res.app`.