# Express Set Session for Specific Routes

Tags: node.js, express, routes, express-session

I am trying to include sessions only for some routes (the authentication ones) but I am having a problem because of the error page routes:

I have this:

```
    app.use(session({
        secret: config.secrets.session,
        saveUninitialized: false,
        resave: false,
        store: sessionStore,
        proxy: true,
        cookie: {
            maxAge: config.token_duration,
            secure: false
        }
        // rolling: false
    }));


    app.use('/api/user', require('./api/user'));
    app.use('/api/auth', require('./api/auth'));  

    app.route(['/error/500','/error/404','/user/settings'])
        .get((req, res) => {
            res.sendFile(path.resolve(app.get('appPath') + '/index.html'));
        });

    app.route('/*/*')
        .get(errors[404]);       

    app.use(errors[500]);
```

So, If I use it like this, all the pages in my application will create a session (which I don't want). If I move the session section after the error routes, I will never get to the api routes because it will reach the 404 route.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Middleware can be associated with only certain routes and the order in which it is specified matters.  There are a number of ways to do that and how to best implement it depends upon the paths your site uses and how you can most easily create a link between path and whether it should or should not have the session middleware on it.

One simple thing to do would be to put your error route handlers BEFORE your session middleware.  Then, those route handlers would "handle" the request first and the session middleware would never get called.

```
app.route(['/error/500','/error/404','/user/settings'])
    .get((req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(app.get('appPath') + '/index.html'));
    });

app.use(session({
    secret: config.secrets.session,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false,
    store: sessionStore,
    proxy: true,
    cookie: {
        maxAge: config.token_duration,
        secure: false
    }
    // rolling: false
}));
```

Other things you can do:

1. Put a path on your session middleware so it is only invoked for certain paths in your site (all authenticated pages should be below that path).
2. Create your own middleware handler that checks to see if the path is `/error` and if not, then it invokes the session middleware handler.  If it is `/error`, then don't invoke the session middleware.

This last one could be done like this:

```
const sessionHandler = session({
    secret: config.secrets.session,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false,
    store: sessionStore,
    proxy: true,
    cookie: {
        maxAge: config.token_duration,
        secure: false
    }
    // rolling: false
});

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    // if path does not start with /error/, then invoke session middleware
    if (req.url.indexOf("/error/") !== 0) {
        return sessionHandler(req, res, next);
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

Comment: I used your first approach, Worked like a charm! I had already tried your last approach but since I am using a security middleware (https://github.com/krakenjs/lusca) I had to call "app.use(session..." instead of holding it in a variable. Thanks!

Comment: @Bernardo - You can hold it in a variable.  I'm not sure why you think that won't work.  In `app.use(session(...))`, the `session()` part is executed only once at app startup and that returns a new middleware function that `app.use()` uses.  That is exactly what my `sessionHandler` example does.  Same thing.

Comment: yeah, I think when I tried I made a mistake when assigning the variable

Comment: Note on above, in the second example, you must call `next()` outside the `if` block, if you have subsequent middleware that is called. I believe `session()` will call `next()` implicitly for handled routes.

Comment: @stephenmc - You are correct.  I've edited to fix.  Thx.

Answer (score 1):

You can also chain/compose multiple middleware using Express.router() as mentioned in this example: [Express: composing middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19341168/express-composing-middleware)

And then apply that composed router (of chained middleware) as a specific route handler.